# jQuery .load() strange behaviour

Tags: jquery

This is not really a coding question(I guess), so I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask it. I encountered weird behaviour of jQuery .load() function. I use it inside father.html like this:

```
<button onclick="$('#test-container').load('child.html');">Test</button>
<div id="test-container"></div>
```

It works just fine. The problem is with changing child.html - then the behavior seems completely random to me. Let's say I had some code in child.html (version1), then I changed it to (version2). I reload father.html and check how it looks - fine. I do some more changes to child.html (version3), reload father.html and suddenly, (version1) is back. What just happened? I reload father.html again and voilà, (version3) is here. Reload again - version(2), again - version(3). It seems to me like even though only (version3) of child.html is saved on the disk/server, my browser somehow remembers all three versions and randomly picks which version to load? Is this behavior normal? How can I stop it? Btw the same problem occurs both locally while using XAMPP, and after uploading on the server.

Comment: It's a browser cache standard behavior, try to append a param to querystring to test the clean load (client.html?v=1)

Comment: As above, but a *different* param each time, not just `?v=1` - you can generate a timestamp to add to the url.  Alternatively, you can configure you page not to cache - but that will depend on your server and/or server-side code details.